# Blank PCB testing of high current traces

Tags: pcb-fabrication, thermal-camera

I have a successful PCB design that conducts 10 amps of current at 27.5 volts. (Drives a DC motor) I desire to have my **blank PCB** manufacturer test the **high current traces** for manufacturing defects that would cause a trace to fail my final full current test.

I believe normal electrical testing of blank PCBs is oriented toward detecting shorts and opens and would not catch traces or vias that conduct but would overheat at high currents.  The problem with this type of testing is that pogo pins are not good at high current, and that burning destroys the defect so any corrective action cannot be determined. It seems probable a solution is already available, but I do not know what to ask the PCB shop for.

One solution might be to selectively heat the pads with a laser or other mechanism, and then use thermal imaging software to analyze the heat distribution pattern compared to a known good board. (I am thinking the heat flow through a flawed trace would be slower.) It is also possible these types of defects are so rare in a reputable manufacturer that the cost of an occasional failure at final test is not worth the investment in up front testing.

Comment: I would think that simply measuring the resistance of the trace would be simpler than selective laser heating.  Have you experienced any failures?  How much do these boards cost you per piece?  It might be simpler to make a test jig yourself if the board is not being populated by the manufacturer.

Comment: Depends on what specifically you're worried about - flex? Thermal expansion and contraction? (Doubtful that a regular PCB shop would be equipped for those.) Bed of nails, DC resistance. If you're feeling fancy, run HF tests that leverage the skin effect and compare transfer function against a known good board.

Comment: How many failures are you getting? We get none, zero for 80A traces. Are the traces internal? External defects should show on visual inspection. What weight are you using? How wide are the traces?

Answer (score 3):

Correct -- if the board exists, and passes basic tests, it's worth taking though assembly and final test. Soldering defects for example are a higher priority than spotty traces.

I can't imagine a proper commercial fabricator having such poor process that cross section would suffer.  Even the toner transfer PCBs I made way back when, weren't *that* bad.  The bigger challenge was getting connectivity on fine traces, which I imagine such a fab would have problems with as well.

More plausible might be inferior foil/plating thickness, but these are specified by industry standards e.g. IPC-600, and you can do spot tests or sampling to verify that your supplier is providing boards to spec.

Final testing could well include a thermal cam on the PCB, hooking up the board to rated current, via intended connectors.  But I suspect you'll find the process improvement (slightly reduced infant mortality and warranty returns) isn't worth the investment (camera, plus vision system to work it, or employee(s) to review it manually, plus additional testing time waiting for it to heat up visibly if applicable).

Statistics and economics tell the true story.  Appreciate that there exists some ideal / equilibrium amount of process dropout: reducing it from gross levels is certainly profitable, but reducing it entirely to zero would likely be cost-prohibitive (e.g. expensive hand rework on an otherwise very low cost board, better instead to just destroy the e.g. 2 in 1000 that fail).

And if you aren't doing enough quantity for either to matter -- you definitely aren't doing enough where an automated test system [of such sophistication] would be warranted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow thanks everybody, definitely helped me narrow my thinking, to considering what types of things could cause the traces to fail and the cost if a small number do. I think I will specify a visual inspection at the board shop, for my trace flaw concerns, this will go with an electrical test, to make sure I don’t have shorts or opens. After reconsidering I realized my design is not high risk, and I can live with failures that will be caught at final test. Here are the answers to the group’s questions. The board cost to me is about $300. (a service call to replace a defective board is a minimum of $2000), My vendor plans to move the board fab and assembly to China, with final assembly and testing in the US. The application is driving a DC motor that stalls at 5 amps with several MOSFETs, the MOSFETS thermally protect themselves after about 4 seconds with a stalled motor. In an actual short condition, the MOSFETs turn off in a few milli seconds. In operation the load is about 500 mA and not continuous. We have 17 years with a similar layout and sell about 100 replacement boards a year into a fleet of 4000. I attribute most of the replacement sales to parts changers in the service group, unfortunately I never get any failed boards back.  The 10 amps is my worst-case target because that is about twice the stall current of the DC motor. We are starting with 2 oz copper and plating to 4, the board is dual sided with a single layer and through plated holes on FR4. The high current traces are 100 mils, I was able to parallel them on the back side so in total I have 200 mil traces, but I think the paralleling scheme probably does not share the load very well.  We have not seen any failures, but we have not run more than 100 through the final test, and the legacy board was not tested at all.  The board is 10 inches long and 2.5 inches wide. The power traces which originate with several MOSFETs run 1.5 inches along the 2.5-inch width, before they connect to a terminal strip. The board is open to the air on the top (component) side and mounted inside a stainless Hoffman style box. I have measured the internal temperature of the enclosure (1,440 in2 surface area) at 130 F in full sunlight with an ambient temperature of 110 F. We use 125 F as the maximum ambient our products can see. Thanks Again.

Comment: It's a bit hard to read when you don't format the text, but this doesn't appear to answer the original question. Remember that this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Russell - Hi, I'm not sure how to interpret your post. You wrote it in the "Your Answer" box. On Stack Exchange, since you asked the original question, that box is only used by an OP if they have answered their own question & need to give a different solution than just upvoting / accepting an answer already been given by someone else. || But you said: "*{...} Here are the answers to the group’s questions {...}*" That's confusing for us, as it's not the kind of answer from an OP which is intended in the "Your Answer" box - *unless* it is also the full & final answer to your original question.

Comment: (continued) Like the comment above, I'm not sure whether you are stating your full & final solution i.e. no more answers needed. (a) Is this your full & final solution? If so, please see [here](/help/someone-answers). You can optionally [áccept](/help/accepted-answer) someone else's answer to indicate your choice of "best answer". Or you can áccept your own answer, no sooner than 48 hours after you asked the question, meaning any time after 22.07 UTC on 2023-09-29. On Stack Exchange, although it is optional, áccepting an answer is the clearest indication that you don't need further answers.

Comment: (continued) Or (b) Were you giving more info, intending to leave the question open for further answers and *not* making this your full & final solution? If so, as the new info doesn't seem (as far as I can tell) to invalidate the existing answer, it should be removed as an "answer" & edited into the question as an update. While we could easily do that for you, I didn't want to do that and then find that you actually *did* intend this post to be your full & final solution. || This has been the long way of saying: Please explain what you intended with your post - is it option (a) or (b)? Thanks.